# Are resource gathering questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Essentially, are questions like "What is a good resource explaining [this specific math topic] in [this specific way]?" and/or "Where can I find a link to an archived copy of [paticular website about mathematics]?" appropriate for math.stackexchange.com? And if not, and you know of a more appropriate place, that would be helpful too.

Comment: AFAIK, the first one is on topic, and there's a tag for that [(reference-request)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request). I've also seen the second one; I remember someone asking about the new name of [Springer's EOM](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Main_Page) or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first one is okay. "Where can I read about X from the viewpoint of general topology? I am aware of Y and Z but in these sources only manifolds are considered, not general topological spaces." [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)

I don't like the second one. Looks like an invitation for group googling.

Comment: (There is no space between the colon and the tag name.)

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the 2nd type. Math.SE isn't just a Q&A, it's a collective wiki as well (figuratively).

Comment: @JenniferDylan Maybe it depends on the nature of the website. The need for archived copy indicates that the website was taken down. Was it shut down because of copyright infringement? Does the website's owner have another good reason to remove the material posted there? We don't know.

Comment: @Leonid: Well, it being an invitation for group Googling would depend on how well the question was asked (e.g. I already googled and couldn't find it and this other site is similar but lacks [something]). However, it sounds like such a question might end up becoming a discussion as to why it was taken down, which doesn't sound very stackexchange-like.

Comment: @helopticor I think there would be no problem if the question focused on content. "There used to be this great website about X, but it is dead now, so where can I find a similar resource on X?"